# Fused location provider behavior in Android 5.0 unexpected

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I am trying to make use of android fused location provider to get the device location every 30 minutes using **PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY**. What is **surprising** to me is that,

When GPS is disabled, I am expecting the API to make use of network provider and sensors to give me location with little bad accuracy. However, location returned by the API in this case is **null for Android 5.0**.

This behavior is different in Android 4.0, it gives me location with little bad accuracy as expected. I cannot find any documentation on this! Any thoughts??

**EDIT:** Just realized that, Device having Android 5.0 do not have a SIM, does this mean that if there is no SIM, fused location provider will not consider WiFi either to find best location?

Comment: this might be of value to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40051181/550393 please also share your findings

Answer (score 0):

Cache will be cleared after device location is closed so you should use LocationRequest with  PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY. You can use LocationCallBack as a weak reference so you can escape from memory leak. You must remove location updates in onStop(). Code like that,

```
            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
            LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                    if (locationResult == null || locationResult.getLastLocation() == null)
                        return;
                    updateLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation());
                }
            };

            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
```