# Android periodic location locationRequest.interval not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fusedlocation, location-services, google-location-services

**TL;DR** :

Android `requestLocationUpdates()` has `locationRequest.interval = 10000` which does not happen, is something wrong?

**In Details**:
Successfully implemented Android period location and it works fine, using this reference https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates

Working Code piece:

```
val fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(
            someActivity
        )

        val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        locationRequest.interval = 10000 //This interval does not work

        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
            somelocationCallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper())
```

After running the code the period updates are coming in random intervals and does not follow any pattern even though `locationRequest.interval = 10000`. Is something is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

The solution is provided here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40051181/10941112

*Reason of the Q&A: 
It took quit long find out the solution with this question, so to provide better searchability the question is raised*